# Unable to connect to Intel Edison Arduino kit

Tags: hardware, edison

I just received my new Intel Edison with Arduino Breakout Kit and after hours trying to connec to it, I just can't.

I connected two USB cables to my computer, the switch between the power suply and the nearest usb cable is set to be near the usb cable as explained here : https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/startup-guide-for-linux-intel-edison-users

And when I connect the two cables, here's `dmesg`:

```
[  +1,675635] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
[  +0,098861] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=8086, idProduct=e005
[  +0,000008] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000005] usb 2-1.2: Product: MERRIFIELD
[  +0,000003] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: INTEL
[  +0,000004] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 10692CA2BC827B2B148DBA29FF184150
[  +9,018609] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 24
[  +0,769033] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 25 using ehci-pci
[  +0,100256] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=8086, idProduct=e005
[  +0,000010] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000005] usb 2-1.2: Product: MERRIFIELD
[  +0,000005] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: INTEL
[  +0,000004] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 10692CA2BC827B2B148DBA29FF184150
[  +0,082352] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 25
[  +2,538308] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 26 using ehci-pci
[  +0,086453] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a99
[  +0,000012] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000006] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB download gadget
[  +0,000005] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Intel
[  +2,657426] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 26
[déc.16 21:14] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 27 using ehci-pci
[  +0,087183] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a9e
[  +0,000010] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  +0,000005] usb 2-1.2: Product: Multifunction Composite Gadget
[  +0,000005] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.10.17-poky-edison+ with dwc3-gadget
[  +0,000004] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 6c1877a6e8f1f5671214d752ae622b8a
[  +0,004451] rndis_host 2-1.2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2, RNDIS device, 96:16:2c:fe:eb:a3
[  +0,001898] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.2: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[  +0,000085] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.2: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  +0,002327] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.4: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0,000287] scsi host13: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.4
[  +0,057754] rndis_host 2-1.2:1.0 enp0s29u1u2: renamed from usb0
[  +0,008595] systemd-udevd[11838]: renamed network interface usb0 to enp0s29u1u2
[  +0,937753] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Linux    File-CD Gadget   0310 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  +0,001719] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  +0,013953] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] 1572864 512-byte logical blocks: (805 MB/768 MiB)
[  +0,001413] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  +0,000009] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0f 00 00 00
[  +0,001013] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  +0,005279]  sdb: sdb1
[  +0,008088] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  +0,391987] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[  +0,000018] SELinux: initialized (dev sdb1, type vfat), uses genfs_contexts
[  +3,143835] rndis_host 2-1.2:1.0 enp0s29u1u2: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2, RNDIS device
[  +0,031230] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  +0,025797] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 27
```

Here, there is first something that bothers me :

> **Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.**

Is this "normal" ? When running fcsk it talks about the dirty bit, I assumed it was a specific reason for Intel.

Reading the dmesg, I can see that the module will be available at ttyACM0, so I try to conenct using:

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200
```

But nothing, a blank screen. I can try to hit enter one, two or millions times, nothing changes.

I'm stuck here for the moment, I don't know what to do more.
For information I'm using Fedora 20 64bits.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Uninstall brltty if it's installed and see if that helps.  Also, I find minicom is better than screen.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I finally found my issue ... and it's dumb as f**k. One of the USB cables is only a power supply cable, it doesn't contain the data cables inside which is needed. I switched the cables and I was able to connect easily...

Comment: D'oh. TBH I fell foul of that once.  I chopped that cable up and used it for something else so I'd never do it again.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the interest of removing a few cables, the cost difference is so low!